# Entering numbers from a specific range and adding them up when their sum reaches a 5-digit number

Tags: c#, while-loop, do-while

I am fairly new to C#. My programming teacher gave me the following problem: I have to make a program that lets you enter numbers from a specific range/interval (the range he gave me was from 10 to 10,000, but you could think of your own).

I have to do it with a 'while' or a "do-while" cycle. Here is where I got to so far:

```
int n, Sum = 0;
        while ((Sum < 10000))
        {
            Console.Write("Type in a number from the interval [10; 9999]: ");
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if ((n <= 10) || (n >= 9999))
                {
                Console.WriteLine("That number isn't in the range!");
                Console.Write("Type in a number from the interval [10; 9999]");
                n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

I'm halfway done, but I don't know how to make the program sum them up, when the sum reaches a 5-digit number. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do a `Sum += n;` when `n` is a valid number (in the interval).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `n` to `Sum`.

So, instead of your second `n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` (which isnt actually doing anything useful, it's just repeating a check you performed earlier), just use `Sum += n;`.

`+=` is a shorter way of saying `Sum = Sum + n`.